# Tidyverse - Gather unite and spread when grouping by multiple variables

Tags: r, tidyverse

I know **this is a very easy question** and I was looking to the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25925556/gather-multiple-sets-of-columns?rq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43293951/using-gather-to-gather-two-or-more-groups-of-columns-into-two-or-more-key) trying to adapt the code for my current question, but I was not successful. 
So, several times, we need to present tables with mean and standard deviation (and other information) by multiple groups. This is a really common analysis, but when we decide to use tidyverse to run that, sometimes the code becomes hard to deal with.

[image: Gather]

I know this code is very close to what I want

```
all_fpc %>% 
  group_by(arm, Time) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(sum_fpc), funs(mean, sd)) %>% 
  gather(key, val, mean:sd) %>% 
  separate(key, into = c('key1', 'key2')) %>% 
  print(n=nrow(.))
```

But I'm stacked here.

To reproduce this dataset, please try this:

```
ds <- data.frame(arm=c("Group 1","Group 2","Group 3", "Group 4"), 
                 Time = c("First","Second","Third"),
                 result = rnorm(n = 120,mean=10,sd=2))
ds %>% 
  group_by(arm, Time) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(result), funs(mean, sd)) %>% 
  gather(key, val, mean:sd) %>% 
  print(n=nrow(.))
```

Second question: Anyone knows any package (based on tidyverse) that can create a pivot table in an easier way?

*Edited: As always, thanks for all suggestions! The answer to this question is below.*

Comment: Do you need `ds %>% group_by(arm, Time) %>% mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% spread(Time, result)`

Comment: You're using `separate` instead of `spread`.

Comment: I always find  `gather` and `spread` confusing, is this what you're looking for, using `reshape2`: `ds %>% reshape2::dcast(arm+Time ~ key, value="val")`

Comment: But equivalently in tidyverse: `ds %>% spread(key,val)`

Comment: @akrun Thanks much as always. I was revisiting some old codes you gave me and I'm almost there. Could you please explain me how to reproduce this output without external packages ? library(ezsummary)
` ds %>%
  select(arm,Time,result) %>% 
  group_by(arm,Time) %>%
  ezsummary(digits = 1)`

Comment: When you're just reshaping the data, rather than actually calculating summary statistics, you typically don't need an explicit group like you do for other types of operations, because a wide/long transformation implies groups based on your ID variables.

Comment: @Mako212 Thanks. I did not know that.

Comment: For pivoting, try `rpivotTable`. Its ugly but functional and surprisingly versatile.

Comment: @Nettle, I'll check this command and I'll come here to tell my results! Thanks for sharing!! =D

Comment: @Nettle, truly amazing! If someone wants to check the final code using this package: ds <- data.frame(group=c("Group 1","Group 2","Group 3", "Group 4"), 
                 Time = c("First","Second","Third"),
                 result = rnorm(n = 120,mean=10,sd=2))

devtools::install_github(c("ramnathv/htmlwidgets", "smartinsightsfromdata/rpivotTable"))
library(rpivotTable) 
rpivotTable(ds,rows="group", cols=c("Time"))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we want to reproduce `ezsummary` output, just `summarise`

```
ds %>% 
   group_by(arm, Time) %>% 
   summarise(variable = 'result', 
             mean = round(mean(result), 1),
             sd = round(sd(result), 1))
```

Comment: I always ask myself how do you know so much about tidyverse....  I was trying to reply this question with "gather" "unite" inspired on your code here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51372723/better-output-with-dplyr-breaking-functions-and-results) 

Thanks *much*!

Comment: @Luis Glad to know that it is helping.  I do code everyday, learn from other code, questions, other languages.  I think as in any other field, practice is the key.  Let's say you devote an hour daily (consistently) for a year in coding, you would be much better in it than your starting point.